# Ftp server shows as completely empty, even without . and .. (current and parent folders)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ftp

I need to retrieve a file that is supposed to be on some FTP server. When I connect to this server, it shows as empty. Maybe they simply failed or forgot to upload the file. But when I connect using the ftp CLI and I try an 'ls', it shows absolutely nothing, **not even the . and .. folders** (current and parent folders). Is that normal?

'ls' output on this server:

```
200 PORT command successful. 81.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx.
150 Opening data connection for file list.
226 Directory transfer complete. (generate:60ms)(send:61ms)
```

'ls' output on a simple empty directory on another server:

```
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 39662
drwxrwsr-x    2 14548      19865               2 May  4 14:33 .
drwxrwsr-x   14 14548      19865              51 May  4 14:33 ..
226-Options: -a -l 
226 2 matches total
```

Comment: Maybe you're not allowed to go up directory.

Answer (score 0):

you may (most likely) have limited access you can't 'browse' any other folders.

The fact you don't see any . or .. is normal when using the ls command, instead if you type

ls -a

This should list the . and ..

The most likely cause is either the folder is empty or they have set your FTP account up with the wrong permissions

Comment: I tried with ls -a, it acted exactly the same. On the other ftp server, . and .. are listed even without the -a option. It's weird, but I guess there's a difference in the configuration somewhere.
<br />
Anyway **I have my file now**, they just hadn't put it on the ftp yet… But I'm still curious as to why there is this difference between this server and mine. It still shows no '.' or '..' in the not-empty-anymore directory.